# Disable Table Designer in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

How can I disable the table designer in Visual Studio? When I got to an SQL file, I just want to see the textual SQL code, without the Designer above it.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When you open a table, don't you get the split view of _T-SQL_ and the _Design_ by default?

Comment: Yes, correct.  But it was the design view I wanted to remove.  You can do this by expanding the TSql part of the view, but I have to do that each time I open the file.
Your answer below is exactly what I wanted though, so thankyou.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In the *Solution Explorer*:

- right click on *yourTable.sql* table definition
- click on *Open with...*
- choose *Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor*
- click on *Set as Default*
- click *Ok*

The steps above will insure that you always will open the table definitions with the T-SQL editor. You can revert back to the default setting by choosing the *Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Editor Selector*.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Nice +1!  In Visual Studio 2017 there is a "with Encoding" option when selecting the T-SQL Editor... do you know what does it mean?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp it allows you to chose a different file encoding, e.g. UTF-8, ASCII etc

Comment: Thank you, god bless you. +1

Comment: Still works in Visual Studio 2022. Thanks!

Comment: It works better, but if the tab is not open and it's still in the preview, the code doesn't show up.